# HIVE QL: How do I extract info from "show partitions table' and use it in a query?

Tags: select, hive, partition

When I want to select the last month from a big table I can do this:

```
select *
from table
where yyyymm=(select max(yyyymm) from table)
```

It takes forever.  But

```
hive> show partitions table
```

only takes a second.

Would it be possible to manipulate `show partitions table` into a text_string and do something like:

```
select *
from table
where yyyymm=(manipulated 'partition_txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing this in Hive but couldn't, so I did it in Spark 2.1.1.

```
val part = spark.sql("SHOW PARTITIONS db.table")
// sorts list in reverse and writes to hdfs myDir
part.sort(col("partition").desc).write.csv.save("myDir")
```